# Trouble after changing number of processors

Tags: cpu, windows-11

I'm using Windows 11 Pro. I was looking for ways to increase performance and I came across some postings on MSCONFIG.

I went to `msconfig-boot` and changed number of processors from 1(default) to 4. Maybe after I faced a problem that after sleep time computers is awake but screen is black.

So, I tried to revert my doing and to keep performance and choose 2. After discovering nothing changed and wanted to go back to default, and I saw that there were no more 3 and 4 options, and after choosing 1 processor 2, 3, 4 options did not come back.

Furthermore, my laptop started to freeze hardly and CPU % is high.

Please any ideas on how to revert all my doing to default?

Comment: uncheck the box next/over the CPU setting, to disable processor control. it will then use all processors. there is never a reason to enable this setting unless you want to reduce the number of CPUs/cores to less than all of them.

Comment: You only have 1 processor. Your processor has multiple cores which supports multiple threads.

Answer (score 1):

Selecting a specific number of processors/cores isn't about performance, it's about working around a software problem you might have (but don't).

Windows runs best when you uncheck *Number of processors' (and everything else in that windows) and use the default, all cores.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you y'all for the answers. I really messed up everything and just reinstalled Windows, now everything is okay. Although the suggestions were correct, I made a mistake after

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).